# Fetching data from BlobStorage via Service.ts and call the function NgOnit

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services, callback

In the service.ts module I retrieve data from the Azure Blobstorage and want to read the contents.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { JsonData } from '../models/jsondata';



import {
  BlobServiceClient,
  BlobDownloadResponseModel
} from "@azure/storage-blob";




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class JsonDataService {
  private account = environment.ACCOUNT_NAME;

  private sas = environment.SAS;
  private blobServiceClient

  constructor() { this.blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${this.account}.blob.core.windows.net${this.sas}`) }


  getData(): Promise<JsonData[]> {

    return new Promise(resolve => {


      const containerName = "output2";
      const containerClient = this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

      //list blobs
      let i = 1;

      async function main() {
        i = 1;
        for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

          // console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
          console.log(blockBlobClient)
          const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
          const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
          console.log(downloadBlockBlobResponse)
          //console.log("Downloaded blob content",download);
          console.log(download)
          return download

        }

      }

      //BROWSER ONLY A HELPER METHOD USED TO CONVERT A BROWSER BLOB INTO STRING
      async function blobToString(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fileReader.onloadend = (ev: any) => {
            JSON.parse(ev.target!.result)
            resolve(ev.target!.result);
            
          };
          fileReader.onerror = reject;


          fileReader.readAsText(blob);


        });
      }

      main().catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
      })

    })

  }

}
```

I test this function with console.log, it returns right data.

Now I want to access this function over the test.component.ts component and I use ngOnit to call this function, but somewhow it only returns meta data and not the returning values by calling the getData() function.

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonDataService } from 'src/app/services/json-data.service';
import { JsonData } from 'src/app/models/jsondata';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  providers: [JsonDataService]
})



export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  jsondatas: Array<JsonData> = [];
  jsondata: JsonData;
  name: String;
  timestamp: number;
  value: number;

  //constructor() { }

  

  constructor(private jsonService: JsonDataService) {
  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsonService.getData()
      .then(results => this.jsondatas = results);

    console.log(this.jsonService)

  }

}
```

This is the result of NgOnit:
[console.log(this.jsonService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERv2l.jpg)

But what I expected are the defined jsondata as like `name, timestamp, value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promise never resolves, it needs to call at the end resolve(myResultJsonDatas) for it to work

example below :

```
  getData(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // Some code
      resolve('myResult');
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, what is 'myResultJsonDatas'? The values which I need to return back is in the async function main() {... const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody) }. But how to pass this value into the arguments of resolve? sorry for that questions, I am a beginner with Angular

Comment: I'm not familiar with async syntax, but you would need to do something like this


resultData = await main().catchError(err => { console.error('message'); return null; });
resolve(resultData);

Comment: thanks, but do I need to call resultData on the NgOnInit Function as well?, because how the test.component.ts module will receive the informations about resultData?

Comment: resultData is a local variable of the promise, resolve function will "transfer" it in the results variable in the component here : "this.jsonService.getData().then(results"

Comment: ok thanks for explanation. So console.log(this.jsonService) actually should return the json string which looks like this {"name": "Michael";
  "timestamp": "1598207249";
  "value": 23 } ?  But somehow I get the metadata (see image in the original post). I guess I mess up with the functions.

Comment: you get metadata because you are logging the function (and not the result of the function), in your case you would need to log it like this : this.jsonService.getData()
      .then(results => { this.jsondatas = results; console.log(this.jsondatas); } );